# Background threads not starting before server shutdown

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, uwsgi

I'm having some trouble getting simple multi-threading functionality up and running in my web application.

Im using Flask, uwsgi, nginx on Ubuntu 12.04.

Each time I start a new thread it will not execute before I shut down the uwsgi server. Its very odd!

If I'm doing a simple task (e.g. printing) it will execute as expected 9/10 times. If I do a heavy computing job (e.g. OCR on a file) it will **always** start executing when the server is restarting (doing a shutdown)

Any idea why my code does not perform as expected?

Code:

```
def hello_world(world):
    print "Hello, " + world # This will get printed when the uwsgi server restarts

def thread_test():
    x = "World!"
    t = threading.Thread(target=hello_world, args=(x,))
    t.start()

@application.route('/api/test')
def test():
    thread_test()
    return "Hello, World!", 200
```

**EDIT 1:**

My uwsgi configuration looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir       = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/
pythonpath  = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/
pythonpath  = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/ml/
module      = app.app:application
master      = True
vacuum      = True
socket      = /tmp/archii.sock 
processes   = 4
pidfile     = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/uwsgi.pid 
daemonize   = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/uwsgi.log
virtualenv  = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/virtualenv/flask/
wsgi-file   = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/app/app.py
ssl         = True
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be waiting for the thread to finish before terminating the process?

Comment: The thread does not even start before I shut down the server.

Comment: Can you show your uWSGI configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question now.

Comment: Are you starting `uwsgi` with threads? From the docs _If you start uWSGI without threads, the Python GIL will not be enabled, so threads generated by your application will never run._

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure if Im stating uwsgi with threads. I do start uwsgi with 4 processes. I believe this is equivalent to enabling threads. I might be wrong?

Comment: You need to config processes and threads (which would be the number of threads per process). Those threads would be used to run multiple requests in the process with the side effect that your threads start to work.

Comment: It works! I needed to add threads = 4 in the uwsgi config file. 
Thank you. Please post your answer so I'm able to reward you with points.

Comment: adding `enable-threads = true` will be enough and it won't create extra threads for each of your workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI server by default will disable threads support for some performance improvements, but you can enable it back using either:

```
threads = 2 # or any greater number
```

or

```
enable-threads = true
```

But **be warned** that first method will tell uWSGI to create 2 threads **for each of your workers** so for 4 workers, you will end up with 8 actual threads.

That threads will work as separate workers, so they are not for your use for background jobs, but using any number of threads greater than one will enable thread support for uWSGI server, so now you can create more of it for some background tasks.